# Nokia Here Maps Heatmap Overlay holes

Tags: javascript, heatmap, here-api

I am working with the Nokia Here maps API, visualising data with a heatmap overlay.  The first time the heatmap provider is added to the map, it appears to be missing tiles and displaying holes in the data as seen below:

[image: Issue with heatmap missing tiles]

It is only after turning the heatmap off and on again or reloading the data that it displays correctly.  It should be displaying as below:

[image]

Is this a known issue? Has anyone encountered this before and have a quick solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My feeling is that this is a bug within the canvas rendering, as I have come across a [similar issue before](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?238246-bug-when-dislpaying-multiple-ImgTileOverlays) (but with overlays). A workaround suggested there seems to work for me here as well. I never get any overlay rendering problems when using **DOM** mode - it seem to get this problem only seems to occur in **Canvas** mode.

To force the library to use the **DOM** mode, change the `<script>` tag by appending `&map=js-p2d-dom` as shown.
Code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"
      src="http://api.maps.nokia.com/2.2.4/jsl.js?with=all&map=js-p2d-dom">
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, we tried this, and it did fix the heatmap issue, but we were not satisfied with the zooming of the map when this mode was enabled.  We ended up removing the heatmap on first load and re-adding it with canvas mode.